# Two legends on the same bar graph R

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have to plot essentially three bar graphs in the same graph, the data looks something like this:

```
mydata = data.frame(var1=c(seq(from=0.1,to=0.5,by=0.1),rep(0,5)),var2=seq(from=0.1,to=1,by=0.1),var3=seq(from=0.1,to=1,by=0.1))

   var1 var2 var3
1   0.1  0.1  0.1
2   0.2  0.2  0.2
3   0.3  0.3  0.3
4   0.4  0.4  0.4
5   0.5  0.5  0.5
6   0.0  0.6  0.6
7   0.0  0.7  0.7
8   0.0  0.8  0.8
9   0.0  0.9  0.9
10  0.0  1.0  1.0
```

Note there are only 5 data values for var1 rather than 10 as for var2 and var3

This is my current attempt at plotting bars for the three variables.

```
colours <- c("white","beige","brown","darkgray","purple","red","green", "orange", "blue", "yellow")
barplot(as.matrix(mydata), main=paste0("Results"), ylab = "Prob", cex.lab = 1.5, cex.main = 1.4, beside=TRUE, col=colours)
legend("topleft", c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"), cex=1.3, bty="n", fill=colours)
```

Which looks like this:

[image: Bar chart of the tree variables]

However there are three problems:

1) Var1 only has five values so I would like it to plot the first values in there (the other values are just filler, so that the data frame works).

2) The legend is only correct for var2 and var3... I would like a separate legend for var1 since the categories for var1 would have a different unit compared to the categories for var2 and var3.

3) There are way too many colours for the bars, a single colour for var1, var2 and var3 with gradient would be good.

Comment: Why do you think that the legend is "only correct for var2 and var3"? A legend should describe all values in the data. You don't need a separate legend simply because one subgroup of the data does not contain those values.

Comment: The legend for var2 and var3 would be in a different unit to the legend for var1. It might take a while to describe the data completely, so I've left it out. It really wouldn't make sense to use the same legend..

Comment: Then you should edit the question so we can better understand the data. Something else to address is whether you really need the subgroups a, b, c... - in other words, is each observation within var1, var2, var3 really a separate category?